# Find the value of CM on the circle below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In the figure, if $C$, $A$ and $N$ are points of tangency , determine $CM$. ($S:CM=2$)
[image]

I try

CNOI is a square
$\therefore CN = l\boxed{}\sqrt2 \implies l_\boxed{}=3\sqrt2\\
FN.MN = DN.IN \implies 9.(6+CM) = DN.3\sqrt2\\
\therefore 18+3CM = DN\sqrt2$

[image]

*out-of-scale figure*

Comment: What is SCM? Also, I think the last line should be $18 + 3CM = DN \sqrt{2}$

Comment: FYI: According to my GeoGebra sketch and some quick-and-dirty coordinate bashing in Mathematica ... Given right triangle $\triangle BDI$ with inscribed circle meeting the legs at $C$ and $N$, if $M$ and $F$ are the points where line $CN$ meets the circle, then these are precisely the midpoints of arcs $BI$ and $ID$. (Thus, for instance, $DM$ and $FB$ are angle bisectors, meeting at $O$.) This is true regardless of the specific lengths $|FN|$ and $|NC|$.

Comment: @TonyMathew  Typing error. Thanks for the alert. Solution: $CM = 2$

Comment: What is S? I don't see it anywhere on the diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As can be see in figure KN is the diameter of a circle which crosses N', where N' is the projection of N on DB. So this
circle is tangent on segment FM at N, that is $KN\bot FM$ , so N must be the mid point of chord FM. In this way we have:

$NM=FN=6\Rightarrow CM=6-4=2$

Comment: Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

$ CN = l\boxed{}\sqrt2 \implies l_\boxed{}=3\sqrt2\\
FN.MN = DN.IN \implies 9.(6+CM) = DN.3\sqrt2\\
\therefore 18+3CM = DN\sqrt2(I)\\
\triangle OFP: OF^2 = 9^2+(3\sqrt2)^2+2.9.3\sqrt2(cos135^o)\implies OF = 3\sqrt{17}\\
\triangle DNO \sim \triangle FPO: \frac{DN}{12}=\frac{3\sqrt2}{3} \implies DN = 12 \sqrt2\\
From(I):18+3CM =12\sqrt2.\sqrt2 \implies 3CM = 6 \therefore \boxed{CM = 2} $

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution, but it's tedious lol. I thought it would be helpful to share nonetheless.

Let $IB = a, ID = b$.
The formula for the incircle radius of $\Delta IDB$ is
$$
ON = \frac{2 \cdot Area(IDB)}{Perimeter(IDB)} \\
\Rightarrow 3\sqrt{2} = \frac{ab}{a^2+b^2 + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \text{  } (1)
$$
Also, we have:
$$
18+3CM = DN\sqrt2 \\
\Rightarrow CM = \frac{(ID - 3\sqrt2)\sqrt2 - 18}{3} \\
\Rightarrow CM = \frac{\sqrt2}{3} b - 8 \text{    } (2)
$$

Using intersecting chords again, but on $FM$ and $IB$, we have:

$$
FC \cdot CM = IC \cdot CB \\
\Rightarrow 15 CM = 3\sqrt2 (IB - IC) \\
\Rightarrow 15 CM = 3\sqrt2 (a - 3\sqrt2) \\
\Rightarrow CM = \frac{\sqrt2}{5}a - \frac{6}{5} (3)
$$

From $(2)$ and $(3)$, we have:
$$
CM = \frac{\sqrt2}{3} b - 8 = \frac{\sqrt2}{5}a - \frac{6}{5} (4)
$$

$(1)$ and $(4)$ gives the following system of equation:
$$
\begin{cases}
3\sqrt{2} = \frac{ab}{a^2+b^2 + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \\
\frac{\sqrt2}{3} b - 8 = \frac{\sqrt2}{5}a - \frac{6}{5}
\end{cases}
$$

After plugging in $b = \frac{3}{5} a + \frac{51 \sqrt2}{5}$ (which can be derived from $(4)$) into $(1)$, we have a quartic equation. I ran each step through Wolframalpha (multiply, square both sides, ...) and arrived at this equation:
$$
\frac{-a^4}{50} - \frac{9 \sqrt2 a^3}{25} + \frac{11 a^2}{5} + \frac{1224 \sqrt2 a}{25} = 0
$$
All of its solutions are $a \in \{ -17 \sqrt2, -9 \sqrt2, 0, 8 \sqrt2 \}$. Therefore $a = IB = 8 \sqrt2$, and CM can be calculated using $(3)$.

Comment: Thanks for help